# Automate the Boring Stuff Collatz Project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on the collatz project in chapter 3 of Automate the Boring Stuff. I have a fully working collatz function for integer inputs, however I'm stuck trying to get the program to run when I add try, except statements for non-integer values.

Here is my code that only works for integer inputs:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return(number // 2)
    else:
        print(3 * number + 1)
        return(3 * number + 1)

print('Type in a number: ')
colNum = int(input())

while colNum != 1:
        colNum = collatz(colNum)
```

Now, heres my code when I add a try/except statement:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return(number // 2)
    else:
        print(3 * number + 1)
        return(3 * number + 1)

def integercheck(inputVal):
    try:
        return int(inputVal)
    except ValueError:
        print('Error: Input needs to be a number.')
        print('Type in a number: ')
        integercheck(input())

print('Type in a number: ')
colNum = integercheck(input())

while colNum != 1:
        colNum = collatz(colNum)
```

and here is the error code I recieve:

```
Type in a number: 
string
Error: Input needs to be a number.
Type in a number: 
string
Error: Input needs to be a number.
Type in a number: 
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.2/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 22, in <module>
    colNum = collatz(colNum)
  File "/Users/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.2/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 3, in collatz
    if number % 2 == 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

To be clear, this program works when I throw in an integer immediately, but it fails to work when I throw in an integer after I've typed in a string. If anyone could help I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: In the recursive case you're implicitly returning None.  When you drop out of a Python function through any code path with no return statement, that's an implicit return None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursive case doesn't return anything, so control reaches the end of the function as the call stack resolves (Python functions implicitly return `None`, hence your error). Change the line:

```
integercheck(input())
```

to

```
return integercheck(input())
```

or avoid recursion entirely. A few additional remarks:

- Avoid `print`ing inside your function. This [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) makes it less reusable.
- `input("")` takes a prompt string that's worth taking advantage of.
- Use `snake_case` in Python per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- `collatz` only does one step of the sequence, so the name is a little misleading. The burden of setting the next iteration falls on the caller, but this does give the caller some flexibility in determining what to do with intermediate values. With that in mind, this function seems like a perfect fit for refactoring to a [generator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/generator), giving the ability to take elements one at a time or run the whole sequence as the calling code sees fit.

A possible rewrite:

```
def collatz(n):
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n //= 2
        else:
            n = 3 * n + 1

        yield n

def get_int(prompt="Enter a number: ", 
            err="Error: Input needs to be a number."):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print(err)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for step in collatz(get_int()):
        print(step)
```

Comment: Thank you! So adding return gives the function a return value instead of it being null.. seems so simple but I didn't know that. Also, really interesting code that I've never seen before, Ill add that to my arsenal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as this book is a beginners guide to Python, and I am n00basF the code I wrote that got this to work is as follows:

```
def collatz(number):
   try:
      number = int(number)
      while (number) != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = number // 2
            print(number)

        elif number % 2 == 1:
            number = 3 * number + 1
            print(number)   
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('ERROR!!! You need to enter an integer.')

print('Enter a number: ')
userNumber = input('>> ')

collatz(userNumber)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I did not try your answer but check @ggorlen reply. There are some common "mistakes" in yours.

Comment: Thanks @David Garcia Bodeg. Like I said I am new to this. I wanted to post my code as it was as I tend to find a lot of answers new people ask involve advanced topics or explanations/subject matter i have not learned yet, so I wanted to post code that was extremely basic. Thank you for the constructive criticism. I went back read ggorlen answer. His tips make great sense. I will definitely work on refactoring my code and implement his advice as I learn more and gain more knowledge and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

My code is below.  To do the exception handling, I put it in a while loop that breaks to call the collatz function.

In my collatz function, it tests to see if the number is 1 first, then proceeds to check if the number is even or odd, and proceeds with the operation to create the new number and prints it. I call the collatz function recursively within my odd / even blocks using my new number.

```py
def collatz(number):

    if int(number) == 1:
        print('')
             
    elif int(number) % 2 == 0:
        newNumber = int(number / 2)
        print(newNumber)
        collatz(newNumber)

    elif int(number) % 2 == 1:
        newNumber = int(3 * number + 1)
        print(newNumber)
        collatz(newNumber)
    
print('Enter a number:')    
while True:         
    try:
        number = int(input())
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a NUMBER:')

collatz(number)
```

Comment: Pro tip: You can use `number//2` to automatically floor the result so you don't have to call `int()` over and over